# Toriod, how many turns of wire to get 100 uH?

Tags: inductor

I need a toroid of 100 uH and handle 15 A.
It will be used in a MPPT wind generator charge controller of 48 volt DC.
I have a yellow iron core toroid ring, 23 mm outer diameter, 13 mm inner diameter and 10 mm high. I have 1 mm enameled copper wire.

Can somebody please tell me how many turns it would require?

Comment: Try using https://mini-ring-core-calculator.software.informer.com/1.2/

Comment: Its difficult to say without knowing the parameters of the toroid. Powdered iron toroids generally used in SMPS outputs are usually yellow color. But without the datasheet its hard to say. An LC meter would help, but then also, there will be uncertainty about the frequency range where you can use the toroid, perhaps you could do a frequency sweep to find out those properties. You may also wan to measure saturation properties.

Comment: L = Al*N^2. This requires you to know the Al value of your core. For saturation, use LI = NAB.

Comment: A random toroid may be made of almost any permeability material. You need to identify the material, or just measure the AL of the toroid.

Comment: You might want to check the temperature of the wire when it's operating in case it damages the insulation. 1.3 mm diameter wire might be a better choice.

Comment: It will likely saturate too much (guesstimate knowing the dimensions and assuming a fairly standard permeability of about 1000). Fix your question with important details about the core. No core-detail = no-answer (just a fairly useless comment/guess).

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the characteristics of your core, you're going to be stuck with cut and try.

If you measure the inductance with, say, 10 turns and it is x uH then you will wind n turns where

n = \$10\cdot \sqrt{x/100}\$

Of course that tells you nothing about the possible saturation of the core, and at 15A that will likely be a significant problem with that small a core size and 100uH (by my guess). Compare commercial cores with known material characteristics to get an idea.

Or, better yet, design your inductor with a known material and geometry and go buy that core before you waste too much time guessing.